# Calling organize imports programmatically

Tags: eclipse, selection, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to execute 'OrganizeImports' programmatically on files that I'm editing programmatically.
My code looks like this:

```
    final ICommandService cmdService = (ICommandService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService    (ICommandService.class);
    if (cmdService != null) {
        final Command cmd = cmdService.getCommand(IJavaEditorActionDefinitionIds.ORGANIZE_IMPORTS);
        final ExecutionEvent execEvt = new ExecutionEvent(cmd, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, compileationUnit, null);

        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().

        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //cmd.executeWithChecks(execEvt);
                    cmd.execute(execEvt);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    getLogger().severe("organize imports failed: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

My problem is that OrganizeImportsAction executes on the current selection which is not the same as the compilation unit I'm editing. I would like to set the selection programmatically on the compilation unit but I don't know how to do that. Or maybe there is another way to trigger OrganizeImports.

thanks,
stefan

Answer (score 1):

May be [this test `ui.org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.quickfix.CleanUpTest`](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.objectteams/tags/CQ/CQ_3784/testplugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/quickfix/CleanUpTest.java) class could offer some clue.
It is based on the [`enable` method in `ui.org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.quickfix.CleanUpTestCase`](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.objectteams/tags/CQ/CQ_3784/testplugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/quickfix/CleanUpTestCase.java) and on the [`org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation` class](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/PerformChangeOperation.java.htm).

You can see `PerformChangeOperation` invoked ink the class [`org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ltk/ui/refactoring/RefactoringWizard.java.htm).